# Swift 3.0 Table cells not popuating when resizing TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, tableview, uitableview

I'm trying to create a Table view that fits half the screen on an Ipad.

To do this I'm using

```
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y:     tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)
```

When this line is commented out the table view fills to whole screen but populates the table cells. When it is not commented out it is the correct size but nothing gets populated.

**Table cell code**

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let cellIdentifier = "cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
 cell.textLabel?.text = "test";

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue and now I feel stupid.

I hadn't linked the table to the class. So I did that and named it leftTable. I removed the line

```
tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y:     tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)
```

and added in

```
var tableView = self.leftTable;
```

It now works like a charm